# Changing a file with values from another file - Bash script

Tags: bash, sed, scripting, for

I am trying to write a script that takes two files as arguments and changes an .svg file with values from a .csv file. Csv file consists of lines with two values; id,colour. I need to find the id in the svg file and add the colour to the line where id matches I don't know if my problem is the sed part, since it gets complicated when variables are introduced within the change, or the script is fundamentally flawed.

```
id=($(cut -f1 -d, $2))
colour=($(cut -f2 -d, $2))
file=$1
name=$(basename -s .svg $1)
name1=$(echo "$name""1")
cat $2 | while IFS=, read id colour; do 
sed -i "s/id=\"'"$id"'\"/id=\"'"$id"'\" style=\"fill:\"'"$colour"'\";\"/" "$1"
done
```

When I use this `sed -i 's/id="ca"/id="ca" style="fill:red;"/' data.svg` this changes the file, but when I change the "ca" with "$id" or '"$id"', it doesn't work.

I've also tried this :

```
cat $2 | while IFS=, read id colour; do 
sed -i 's/id='"$id"'/id='"$id"' style="fill:red;"/' "$1"
done
```

the result I am getting is this: `<g id= style="fill:red;""hi">`
the expected result was this :
`<g id="hi" style="fill:red;">`

And when I put $colour to sed, `sed -i 's/id='"$id"'/id='"$id"' style="fill:'"$colour"';"/' "$1"` like this, I get this: `<g id= style="fill:;""hi">`

Comment: If I were at you, I would use while loop instead and use break statement where it is not matching. Could you explain this question a little bit more with some more example?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. You shouldn't need to read the CSV into variables, you can just loop on the CSV directly:

```
cat data.csv | while IFS=, read id colour; do # something with $id and $colour
```

2. Doing `var=$(echo text)` is kind of redundant - you should just use `var="text"` directly.
3. I'm not sure what you mean by the construct `[ "grep -E..." ]`, but that is basically testing if the string in the test is not empty, which it isn't because you just put some text in it.

When writing bash scripts it is a good idea to test each expression in turn and see that it behaves as you expect, from the command line (*) - this way a lot of surprises will be eliminated. Writing a complete script and then running it, without a lot of experience on how to write scripts well, is probably a good way to shoot yourself in the foot. I have many years of experience writing bash scripts, and I still try and fail a lot on the command line before putting things down to script. When you do run your script, running it with `-x` to enable tracing of the commands will prove very helpful.

I would guess that the main reason you can't get the replacement to work is that the SVG file uses double quotes (`"`) for the ID attribute and not single quotes as in your `sed` expression.

When constructing `sed` expressions in a shell script, its often annoying to deal with all the escaping. If possible I usually like to have the `sed` expression not quoted at all, which is one of the reasons why I often use regexp delimiters that aren't slashes (as we will next see). You need to put in the values of the `id` and `colour` into the `sed` expression while also correctly identifying the quoting of the SVG attributes. One thing that might work would be this:

```
sed -i "s,id=\"$id\",id=\"$id\" style=\"fill:$colour;\"," "$1"
```

Here we just used double quotes around the expression - which allows us to embed the variables - and just escape the double quotes to match to prevent them from terminating the shell string.

Another option would be to composed the `sed` expression from multiple strings that have different quoting rules:

```
sed -i 's,id="'"$id"'",id="'"$id"'" style="fill:'"$colour"';",' "$1"
```

Here we put all the static text in single quotes, and then just terminate the single quotes and open a double quoted string to have the variables parsed. This works because there are no spaces between the single quoted strings and the double quoted strings, and as long as there are no spaces, Bash passes all that as a single argument to `sed`. But Obviously that's a bit confusing, so I prefer the first style.

Another thing that we can do, is to use `sed` capture groups to not type `id="$id"` more than once:

```
sed -i "s,\(id=\"$id\"\),\1 style=\"fill:$colour;\"," "$1"
```

The `\(` and `\)` capture the thing that was matched, and `\1` drops it back into the substituted string.
*) If you have done scripting in MS-Windows you are probably aware of the sad sad situation there where the command line (whether CMD or powershell) behaves differently then running the same commands in scripts, in often non-obvious ways. This is **not** the situation in Unix scripting shells such as Bash.

Comment: Well what I tried to do with if was "if you match the id, then use this sed to change it."  What can I do to correct my sed, I feel like I've tried every possible combination of quotes?

Comment: Did you try to just run the `sed` command, manually, with one id and color? did it output an error or just copied the file as is?

Comment: It works manually with a specific id and colour. But when I put the variables in, it doesn't and I get this error message: Error reading SVG:Error domain 1 code 5 on line 53 column 1 of data: Extra content at the end of the document

Comment: Can you share the sed command that works?

Comment: sed -i 's/id="ca"/id="ca" style="fill:red;"/' data.svg

Comment: Well - it works when you use double quotes around the id - in your script you use single quotes , and that doesn't work. Use double quotes in your script. Also, you probably want to add this example to the question.

Comment: I updated my answer

Comment: I've used this one `sed -i "s,\(id=\"$id\"\),\1 style=\"fill:$colour;\"," "$1"` and nearly all of them changed,  but there are a few that didn't change. Also script sometimes changed <g> tag but mostly <path> tag is changed in svg.

Comment: If the `id` matches, it will change. If you want to only change `<path>` elements with matching ID and not `<g>` elements with the correct ID, then your expression needs to support that :-) Generally, using a regular language to process XML (a non-regular language) is considered a bad idea: https://stackoverflow.com/q/6751105/53538

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/102044/discussion-between-arthionne-and-guss).